# Set HttpRequestHeader.Accept in Xamarin.Forms c#

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, httpwebrequest

I have tried this, but its not working:

```
httpWebRequestusr.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Accept] = "application/vnd.api+json";
```

It is works fine in native uwp app, but not in xamarin.forms.

I get the following msg:
The 'Accept' header must be modified using the appropriate property or method.
Parameter name: name

What is the best way to set "Accept"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either set it on the `HttpClient` if you want it to be for all requests:

```
HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json");
```

Or just on the one request:

```
httpWebRequestusr.Headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
```

As we gathered from our little chat below this answer, you are using the `HttpWebRequest` object. Then you could simply use: `httpWebRequestusr.Accept = "application/json";`

Comment: The HttpClient is not good for me, the second might be good but theres no Accept property in the "Headers". :/

Comment: You should replace `HttpClient` with the variable that holds an instance to your client. Or do you mean you don't use the HttpClient?

Comment: Yeah, i dont want to use Httpclient. I need to use HttpWebRequest.

Comment: Set it directly then: `httpWebRequestusr.Accept = "application/json";`